# UISlider's value changes to values outside of range

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement a UISlider that has a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 10. I set up an IBOutlet for the slider and an IBAction for when the slider's value changes. Here is my code:

```
//scale is the slider, and scaleValue is a label that displays the slider's value.
- (IBAction)scaleChanged
{
    scaleValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", scale.value];
    NSLog(scaleValue.text);
}
```

The problem is what NSLog gives me:

```
[Session started at 2011-07-25 20:36:22 -0700.]
2011-07-25 20:36:25.626 LineModel[1672:207] 0
2011-07-25 20:36:25.861 LineModel[1672:207] 0
2011-07-25 20:36:25.877 LineModel[1672:207] 0
2011-07-25 20:36:25.894 LineModel[1672:207] -536870912
2011-07-25 20:36:25.911 LineModel[1672:207] -536870912
2011-07-25 20:36:25.928 LineModel[1672:207] -1073741824
2011-07-25 20:36:25.944 LineModel[1672:207] 1610612736
2011-07-25 20:36:25.961 LineModel[1672:207] 1073741824
2011-07-25 20:36:25.978 LineModel[1672:207] 1073741824
2011-07-25 20:36:25.994 LineModel[1672:207] 1073741824
2011-07-25 20:36:26.011 LineModel[1672:207] 1073741824
2011-07-25 20:36:26.028 LineModel[1672:207] -2147483648
2011-07-25 20:36:26.044 LineModel[1672:207] 0
2011-07-25 20:36:26.061 LineModel[1672:207] -2147483648
```

You get the idea. Now, I know the slider's value is a float and not an integer, but the strange thing is that it was actually working fine before, when I had the maximum set instead at 50. Now, though, even if I set the maximum back to 50, it still prints this out. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your NSLog is not following the right syntax, write like this

```
 NSLog(@"%@",scaleValue.text);
```

instead  `NSLog(scaleValue.text);`

Try this

```
- (IBAction)scaleChanged
{
    scaleValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", scale.value];
    NSLog(scaleValue.text);
}
```

Comment: Okay, changed it, and I'm still getting the same values. It shows that on the label too, so I'm not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Okay, so that worked. The only problem with that is that I need them to be whole values, but I was able to solve that by using a "middle-man" (an int called value assigned to scale's value), and then putting that on the label.